# Is it possible to change the tag name for a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job. I selected the option to create a tag for every build. The tag is created but I would like to use the same build name for my new tag, instead the default jenkins tag assigned.

For example, this is the tag created by Jenkins: "jenkins-MyProject-Weekly-159"

And I would like to create the a tag name like: "1.0.126" (which it is my build name).

I am not talking about publishing the tag to Git, just creating the jenkins tag.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "jenkins tag".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jenkins plugin: Build Name Setter Plugin.
Documentation on how to use it:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin